# Logout issue with PassportJs / Oauth / GoogleStrategy

Tags: node.js, oauth, passport.js

I am writing an application using Nodejs and passportjs with Google Strategy. After logging out, the user is still able to login again without entering credentials. How can the user be made to enter credentials again? This can be a big issue on shared computers.

The front end is built using create-react-app that runs on port 3000. For requests related to authentication, a proxy running on port 5000(nodejs server) is used. The code given below is hosted on port 5000

```
app.use(
    session({
        cookie: {maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000},
        secret: [keys.cookieKey], 
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false
    })
);

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

```
    passport.use(
        new GoogleStrategy(
          {
            clientID: googleClientID,
            clientSecret: googleClientSecret,
            callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
            proxy: true
          }, 
          async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    
            const existingUser = await User.findOne({googleId: profile.id});
            
            if(existingUser){
                return done(null, existingUser);
            }
            
            const user = await new User({ googleId : profile.id}).save();
            
            done(null, user);
            
          } 
        )
    );
```

```
    app.get('/api/logout', (req, res) => {
        
        console.log(req.user.accessToken);
        
        if(req.session.passport){ delete req.session.passport; }
            
        req.session.destroy(function (err) {
            req.logout();
            req.logOut();
            req.user = null;
            res.clearCookie('connect.sid');
            res.redirect('/'); 
        });
    });
```

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    ["/api", "/auth/google"],
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "http://localhost:5000",
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: Passport relies on session to store some variables. Id these variables does not exist, user is redirected to the login. If session is destroyed, have the same effect.

Comment: Print **req.session.passport** before and after session destroy and in the router after  success login. Share us the result

Comment: @JRichardsz Before session destroy it prints { user: '5edbc8f0e49ad419ac3a3b32' }. After session destroy it prints "Cannot read property 'passport' of undefined"

Comment: And in your '/' route what is printed before and after logout when redirect is performed?

Comment: @JRichardsz. The front end is built using create-react-app that runs on localhost:3000. It serves the index.html file for '/' route. For requests related to authentication, a proxy running on localhost:5000(nodejs server) is used. The code given above is hosted on localhost:5000.

Answer (score 0):

For advanced configurations like logout, passport,a proper session configuration is the key:

Try with this:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: "changeme",
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  rolling: true,
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
    maxAge: (5 * 1000)
  }
}));
```

This was used in

https://github.com/utec/geofrontend-server

A mini server implementation for client side javascript applications, like your react app. I think it will useful for you. Also you can customize the security!